# How to convert Unicode dict to dict

Tags: python

I am trying to convert :

```
datalist = [u"{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/2/_/2_12.jpg',largeimage: 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/_/2_12.jpg'}",
 u"{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/3/_/3_13.jpg',largeimage: 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/_/3_13.jpg'}",
 u"{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/5/_/5_3_1.jpg',largeimage: 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/5/_/5_3_1.jpg'}",
 u"{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/1/_/1_22.jpg',largeimage: 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/_/1_22.jpg'}",
 u"{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/4/_/4_7_1.jpg',largeimage: 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/4/_/4_7_1.jpg'}"]
```

To list containing python dict. If i try to extract value using keyword i got this error:

```
for i in datalist:
    print i['smallimage']
   ....:     

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-686ea4feba66> in <module>()
      1 for i in datalist:
----> 2     print i['smallimage']
      3 

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How do i convert list containing Unicode Dict to Dict..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/) module which has a non-strict mode that handles the data you have:

```
import demjson

for data in datalist:
    dct = demjson.decode(data)
    print dct['gallery'] # etc...
```

Comment: Good find. Jon.  I like it. (+1)

Comment: I still don't see the need for any of this... Why import anything when you can simply `[dict((str(key), value) for (key, value) in adict.items()]`

Comment: @bnlucas because there are no dictionaries at that stage?

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. Saved my day :-)

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I'd hand-craft a regular expression to make these into something you can evaluate as Python:

```
import re
import ast
from functools import partial

keys = re.compile(r'(gallery|smallimage|largeimage)')
fix_keys = partial(keys.sub, r'"\1"')

for entry in datalist:
    entry = ast.literal_eval(fix_keys(entry))
```

Yes, this is limited; but it works for *this* set and is robust as long as the keys match. The regular expression is *simple* to maintain. Moreover, this doesn't use any external dependencies, it's all based on batteries already included.

Result:

```
>>> for entry in datalist:
...     print ast.literal_eval(fix_keys(entry))
... 
{'largeimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/_/2_12.jpg', 'gallery': 'gal1', 'smallimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/2/_/2_12.jpg'}
{'largeimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/_/3_13.jpg', 'gallery': 'gal1', 'smallimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/3/_/3_13.jpg'}
{'largeimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/5/_/5_3_1.jpg', 'gallery': 'gal1', 'smallimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/5/_/5_3_1.jpg'}
{'largeimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/_/1_22.jpg', 'gallery': 'gal1', 'smallimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/1/_/1_22.jpg'}
{'largeimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/4/_/4_7_1.jpg', 'gallery': 'gal1', 'smallimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/4/_/4_7_1.jpg'}
```

Comment: @Downvoter would you kindly explain the reason for downvoting

Comment: (I didn't downvote this), but this will fail if the values in the dict contain any of those strings.  It will also fail if there are other keys which weren't mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Didn't downvot either. I would use a regex similar to this: `(?:{|,)([^:]+)`

Comment: Why use any of this?? See my answer, it's not importing anything, it's not running regex on anything.

Comment: @bnlucas: Did you test your solution on the sample data at all?

Comment: Since this already parses in both demjson and Yaml, manual quotes struck me as doing more work than needs to be done, but I didn't `-1` you.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: I wasn't aware of demjson, which is a better solution (Jon got my vote).

Comment: @cwallenpoole -- to this answer's credit, it doesn't bring any dependencies to the problem that aren't already in the standard library.  For some projects, you don't want to bring in a bunch of dependencies that your users need to install before they can start using it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Neither was I. I'm glad to add that to my bag 'o tricks.

Comment: @mgilson That's a good part of the reason that I didn't `-1` it. It's a legit solution and, if this data set never changes, it works (and there is a lot to be said for that), but how often is "unchanging data set" a guarantee?

Comment: @cwallenpoole: given that a XPath was used, we can assume this is either XML or HTML, most likely the latter. If that dataset changes, you'll most likely have to adjust a lot more. This is someone scraping websites. (See the [first post revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17147900/1)).

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- FWIW -- I generalized your solution in only a few more lines of code using a little bit more AST magic... I really like that module.  It's amazing how often I go back to it. :)

Comment: @mgilson: nice; Note that your solution only works if the keys are valid Python identifiers; I haven't looked, but there could be a disconnect between valid JavaScript object keys and Python names that would break that.

Answer (score 3):

Just as another thought, your list is properly formatted Yaml.

```
> yaml.load(u'{foo: "bar"}')['foo']
'bar'
```

And if you want to be really fancy and parse everything at once:

```
> data = yaml.load('['+','.join(datalist)+']')
> data[0]['smallimage']
'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/2/_/2_12.jpg'
> data[3]['gallery']
'gal1'
```

Answer (score 2):

If your dictionary keys were quoted, you could
use `json.loads` to load the string.

```
import json
for i in datalist:
   print json.loads(i)['smallimage']
```

(`ast.literal_eval` would have worked too...)

however, as it is, this will work with an old-school `eval`:

```
>>> class Mdict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self,key):
...        return key
... 
>>> eval(datalist[0],Mdict(__builtins__=None))
{'largeimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/_/2_12.jpg', 'gallery': 'gal1', 'smallimage': 'http://www.styleever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/445x370/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/2/_/2_12.jpg'}
```

**Note that this is probably vulnerable to injection attacks, so only use it if the string is from a trusted source.**

---

Finally, for anyone wanting a short, although somewhat dense solution that uses only the standard library and isn't vulnerable to injection attacks... This little gem does the trick (assuming the dictionary keys are valid identifiers)!

```
import ast
class RewriteName(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Name(self,node):
        return ast.Str(s=node.id)

transformer = RewriteName()
for x in datalist:
    tree = ast.parse(x,mode='eval')
    transformer.visit(tree)
    print ast.literal_eval(tree)['smallimage']
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- You're right (bummer).  I suppose the easiest (although not safest) approach is to use regular `eval` ... :-(

Comment: Nice trick with transforming names to strings; this'll work as long as the keys are also valid Python identifiers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- right.  Hadn't thought about that stipulation.  I suppose that's also present in my original answer...

Comment: These are [ECMAScript `IdentifierName` strings](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6), which means they'll use Unicode characters and can start with a `$` or a unicode *letter*. On Python 3, as long as the identifier doesn't start with `$` you should be fine. On Python 2 you are limited to ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Your datalist is a `list` of unicode strings.

You could use `eval`, except your keys are not properly quoted. what you can do is requote your keys on the fly with `replace`:

```
for i in datalist:
    my_dict = eval(i.replace("gallery", "'gallery'").replace("smallimage", "'smallimage'").replace("largeimage", "'largeimage'"))
    print my_dict["smallimage"]
```

Comment: use `ast.literal_eval` over `eval` whenever you can

Answer (score -4):

I don't see why the need for all the extra things such as using `re` or `json`...

```
fdict = {str(k): v for (k, v) in udict.items()}
```

Where `udict` is the `dict` that has `unicode` keys. Simply convert them to `str`. In your given data, you can simply...

```
datalist = [dict((str(k), v) for (k, v) in i.items()) for i in datalist]
```

Simple test:

```
>>> datalist = [{u'a':1,u'b':2},{u'a':1,u'b':2}]
[{u'a': 1, u'b': 2}, {u'a': 1, u'b': 2}]
>>> datalist = [dict((str(k), v) for (k, v) in i.items()) for i in datalist]
>>> datalist
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

No `import re` or `import json`. Simple and quick.

Comment: This doesn't work for the given sample data, **at all**: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'`. The input is a list of unicode string, **not** a list of dictionaries.

Comment: I was going off the question title, so I apologize for not fitting the example data. I see now how each item is a string. My answer **will** convert a `unicode` `dict` to a regular `dict`.

Comment: In such cases I'd not use `str()` but instead explicitly encode.