# Extracting a specific part of a string with regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have such a string below and I want to extract the url just after the `imgurl:`. How could you do in Python in handy way?

```
{ns:"images",k:"5049",mid:"551FC833EDC139718135AA91A46D6B09FE89E85C",surl:"http://www.thewritingnut.com/blog-challenge/az-day-25-yellow-symbolisms/",imgurl:"http://www.thewritingnut.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/yellow-rose-800.jpg",oh:"199",tft:"0",oi:"http://www.thewritingnut.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/yellow-rose-800.jpg"}
```

Comment: Where do get that structure from? Isn't that a dictionary?

Comment: say, what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a String to Dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary) There is no need to use regex here. Just convert the data into a more manageable form.

Comment: One way is to use `demjson` a non-strict json parser - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147900/how-to-convert-unicode-dict-to-dict/17148097#17148097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, using a regular expression:

```
data = '{ns:"images",k:"5049",mid:"551FC833EDC139718135AA91A46D6B09FE89E85C",surl:"http://www.thewritingnut.com/blog-challenge/az-day-25-yellow-symbolisms/",imgurl:"http://www.thewritingnut.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/yellow-rose-800.jpg",oh:"199",tft:"0",oi:"http://www.thewritingnut.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/yellow-rose-800.jpg"}'

re.search('imgurl:"([^"]+)', data).group(1)
```

Comment: Yes or `re.search('imgurl:"(.+?)"',data).group(1)`

Comment: This is crazy. If it's JSON or a dictionary, convert to dict and use appropriate appropriate search in dictionary -- like on key or using regex on the value. Rigging up a regular expression search on a dictionary-as-string just because OP asked for that is not a good answer, IMO.